# how to drop a shape into specified class canvas

Tags: kineticjs

Hi i'm using kineticjs and I was wondering how it is possible to drop a shape into a specified class canvas. So if i have 5 canvas with the same class this is where i could drop my shape into. If its not dropped in one of these canvas it goes back where it was! The only code i have for right now is my shape i've created.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 965,
    height: 200
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();    
  var poly = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 75,
    y: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(poly);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kineticJS has a

```
 .moveTo();  // (  node.moveTo(container);  )
```

method. Example:

```
 poly.moveTo(stage);
```

or if you have multiple canvases like stage1, stage2, stage3:

```
 poly.moveTo(stage1); poly.moveTo(stage2); poly.moveTo(stage3);
```

you will also need to create a listener which returns a container given mouse coordinates. So that when you do 'mousemove' or 'touchmove' you can determine which 'container/stage' you are in. And if you are in a valid container then move the shape to it.

I personally think it would be easier to create one stage, and divide it into parts, and make those parts layers of a fixed size, this way you can just do:

```
 var coordinates = stage.getUserPosition();
```

and use that to determine which layer to place the object in (layer is type of container)

Comment: let me know if this helped you out